# Combining the help message of two different arguments using argparse

Tags: argparse, python-3.8

I'm writing a code that is required to be compatible with Python-3.8+, and it have a CLI. In this CLI I have an optional argument that is supposed to be a boolean flag. I define it as such:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test parser")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
group.add_argument('--feature', action='store_true', dest='feature', help="help 1")
group.add_argument('--no-feature', action='store_false', dest='feature', help="help 2")
group.set_defaults(feature=True)
```

The command behave as expected, however, my problem lies with the help message. Whenever it shows up, it would look like this:

```
usage: test [--feature | --no-feature]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --feature             help 1
  --no-feature          help 2
```

How should I modify this code so the output of the help message is instead something like the help message we get when using python-3.9+ `action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction` while remaining compatible for Python3.8+ ?

The output I expect should look like this:

```
usage: test [--feature | --no-feature]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                 show this help message and exit
  --feature, --no-feature    help 1 & 2
```

Comment: You can't easily.  The 3.9 feature is produced by a new Action subclass.  You'd have to copy that code to your's

Comment: @hpaulj Ah, that's what I was afraid of, I thought there might be a solution which did not involve doing this. Guess I'll stick to that if nobody propose another solution. Thank you !

Comment: In 3.9 it's actually one argument that accepts both the `--foo` and `--no-foo` flags.  There's nothing special about its help display.  What's different is how it sets a different value based on the presence of the `no` word in the flag.